# [Vue]How to use slot-scope in Loop Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I design a tree component,use the loop component to show the leaf relation.The problem occured when I want to modify the label to show pic or icon.
Like this.

```
<img ...>1
<icon ...>2
```

But I don't know how to use slot-scope in Loop Component.

```
component:'tree':
<template>
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...
            <slot :data='data'>
            </slot>
            ...
            <tree ....>
                <slot><!--How to show the slot???--></slot>
            </tree>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

If use `<slot :data='data'></slot>` in tree,it only shows the parent node(level 1).Like this

```
<img ...>1
    <img ...>1  (there should be 1-1)
    <img ...>1  (there should be 1-2)   
<img ...>2
```

If use `<slot :data='data.children'></slot>`,it must throw exception.
Can I use the slot-scope in loop component?If Don't use loop,how to show the relation?
If anyone can give me some help,thanks.

Comment: Did you read this? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Yes,of course.After read that ,I know the 'slot-scope' can be used in parent component,But what should I do in the Loop Component like tree.I use the selfish component to show the tree structure

Comment: I have read some projects,one of them use the fixed structure.That Decide icons will be shown before the label.And my thought is that **I don't know what will be shown before label**,only the parent component will decide.